# WebSockets not working without WebApp

Tags: java, tomcat, bugzilla, embedded-tomcat-8

This works:

```
String webappDir = "...";
context = tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webappDir).getAbsolutePath());
```

This doesn't:

```
context = tomcat.addContext("/", new File("").getAbsolutePath());
```

I don't really need a `webappDir` in this instance because I am not serving any JSP pages or client-side resources, I'm simply using `response.getWriter().println(...);` server-side only.

There is no exception being thrown, the websocket simply does not open.

Can I assume that this is a tomcat bug?

Comment: If you do not need a web application context you can use the Java API for WebSockets JSR 356 directly instead of tomcat websockets API.

Comment: You can create your client as standalone Java app with JSR 356, to build a server you can use any Java EE server container with websockets support, embedded or not (GlassFish, Apache Tomcat, Jetty...) to deploy a WebSocketServlet and listen for client messages.

Comment: I think is not possible, the websockets API is designed for using sockets in web applications so you need a container, if you do not need a web application do not use websockets, use simply Java sockets.

Comment: I have not the habit of talking to myself, the author of the question has removed all his comments, people never ceases to amaze me...

Comment: @vzamanillo: Your comments are good and need to be read. The show more comments link would not make that possible.

Answer (score 3):

well, those two are completely different function. If you look at the javadoc for the function `addContext`, you can see that, you need to setup the context to be able to use websocket. this is retrieved from the api doc.

> Add a context - programmatic mode, no default web.xml used. This means
>   that there is no JSP support (no JSP servlet), no default servlet and
>   no web socket support unless explicitly enabled via the programmatic
>   interface.

So, in your case, I guess you can follow the test case in this [link](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/test/org/apache/tomcat/websocket/TestWsRemoteEndpoint.java?view=annotate) how to add an end point into the context.

As for whether you can assume that this is a bug or not. Personally, I don't think this is a bug as the developer itself already mention that they don't provide the web socket connection. But, to make sure, you may contact them and ask ;).

Comment: Of course you can use websocket. What i mean is that you need more effort to set it up as it doesn't come "free". If i have time, I'll try to see your git repo.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the tests (test/org/apache/tomcat/websocket in the source code), they do

```
tomcat.addContext("", null);
```

Note that passing `null` instead of a context path needs a recent Tomcat 8 (no older than several months). The current version is 8.0.22.

> Can I assume that this is a tomcat bug?

The rule "before filing a bug" is to ask on the users' mailing list, not on stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, the tests in 8.0.21 use that API.